# creating a pdf from a template in itextsharp and outputting as content disposition.

Tags: itext

I would like to open an existing pdf, add some text and then output as content disposition using itext sharp. I have the following code. Where it falls down it is that i want to output as memory stream but need to filestream to open the original file.

Here's what i have. Obviously defining PdfWriter twice won't work.

```
   public static void Create(string path)
    {
        var Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        System.IO.MemoryStream m = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, m);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        document.NewPage();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
        document.Close();
        Response.OutputStream.Write(m.GetBuffer(), 0, m.GetBuffer().Length);
        Response.OutputStream.Flush();
        Response.OutputStream.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems that I'll try to walk you through.

First, the `Document` object is only for working with new PDFs, not modifying existing ones. Basically the `Document` object is a bunch of wrapper classes that abstract away the underlying parts of the PDF spec and allow you to work with higher level things like paragraphs and reflowable content. These abstractions turn what you think of "paragraphs" into raw commands that write the paragraph one line at a time with no relationship between lines. When working with an existing document there's no safe way to say how to reflow text so these abstractions aren't used.

Instead you want to use the `PdfStamper` object. When working with this object you have two choices for how to work with potentially overlapping content, either your new text gets written on top of existing content or your text gets written below it. The two methods `GetOverContent()` or `GetUnderContent()` of an instantiated `PdfStamper` object will return a `PdfContentByte` object that you can then write text with.

There's two main ways to write text, either manually or through a `ColumnText` object. If you've done HTML you can think of the `ColumnText` object as using a big fixed-position single row, single column `<TABLE>`. The advantage of the `ColumnText` is that you can use the higher level abstractions such as `Paragraph`.

Below is a full working C# 2010 WinForms app targeting iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 that show off the above. See the code comments for any questions. It should be pretty easy to convert this to ASP.Net.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string existingFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "file1.pdf");
            string newFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "file2.pdf");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(existingFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER)) {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                        doc.Open();

                        doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a test"));

                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Bind a PdfReader to our first document
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(existingFile);
            //Create a new stream for our output file (this could be a MemoryStream, too)
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
                //Use a PdfStamper to bind our source file with our output file
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs)) {

                    //In case of conflict we want our new text to be written "on top" of any existing content
                    //Get the "Over" state for page 1
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

                    //Begin text command
                    cb.BeginText();
                    //Set the font information
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1250, false), 16f);
                    //Position the cursor for drawing
                    cb.MoveText(50, 50);
                    //Write some text
                    cb.ShowText("This was added manually");
                    //End text command
                    cb.EndText();

                    //Create a new ColumnText object to write to
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
                    //Create a single column who's lower left corner is at 100x100 and upper right is at 500x200
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(100,100,500,200);
                    //Add a higher level object
                    ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("This was added using ColumnText"));
                    //Flush the text buffer
                    ct.Go();

                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

As to your second problem about the `FileStream` vs `MemoryStream`, if you look at the method signature for almost every (actually *all* as far as I know) method within iTextSharp you'll see that they all take a `Stream` object and not just a `FileStream` object. Any time you see this, even outside of iTextSharp, this means that you can pass in any subclass of `Stream` which includes the `MemoryStream` object, everything else stays the same.

The code below is a slightly modified version of the one above. I've removed most of the comments to make it shorter. The main change is that we're using a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream`. Also, when we're done with the PDF when need to close the `PdfStamper` object before accessing the raw binary data. (The `using` statment will do this for us automatically later but it also closes the stream so we need to manually do it here.)

One other thing, never, ever use the `GetBuffer()` method of the `MemoryStream`. It sounds like what you want (and I have mistakenly used it, too) but instead you want to use `ToArray()`. `GetBuffer()` includes uninitialized bytes which usually produces corrupt PDFs. Also, instead of writing to the HTTP Response stream I'm saving the bytes to array first. From a debugging perspective this allows me to finish all of my iTextSharp and `System.IO` code and make sure that it is correct, then do whatever I want with the raw byte array. In my case I don't have a web server handy so I'm writing them to disk but you could just as easily call `Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)`

```
string existingFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "file1.pdf");
string newFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "file2.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(existingFile);
byte[] bytes;
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(100,100,500,200);
        ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("This was added using ColumnText"));
        ct.Go();

        //Flush the PdfStamper's buffer
        stamper.Close();
        //Get the raw bytes of the PDF
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}

//Do whatever you want with the bytes
//Below I'm writing them to disk but you could also write them to the output buffer, too
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you SO much for explaining what the `Document` and `PdfStamper` objects are! I couldn't find these explanations anywhere. I was trying to find out how to add an image to a `PdfReader` object, but from your example, I realized I can do so using a `PdfStamper` object and a `PdfContentByte` object. Wish there was a quick reference document about what each method did, what each property is for, and what classes should be used in certain circumstances. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The second part of your question title says:

> "outputting as content disposition"

If that's what you **really** want you can do this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DESIRED-FILENAME.pdf");
```

Using a `MemoryStream` is unnecessary, since `Response.OutputStream` is available. Your example code is calling `NewPage()` and **not** trying to add the text to an **existing** page of your PDF, so here's one way to do what you asked:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";    
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=itextTest.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(readerPath);
// store the extra text on the last (new) page
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(null);
ct.AddElement(new Paragraph("Text on a new page"));
int numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
int newPage = numberOfPages + 1;
// get all pages from PDF "template" so we can copy them below
reader.SelectPages(string.Format("1-{0}", numberOfPages));
float marginOffset = 36f;
/*
* we use the selected pages above with a PdfStamper to copy the original.
* and no we don't need a MemoryStream...
*/
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, Response.OutputStream)) {
// use the same page size as the __last__ template page    
  Rectangle rectangle = reader.GetPageSize(numberOfPages);
// add a new __blank__ page      
  stamper.InsertPage(newPage, rectangle);
// allows us to write content to the (new/added) page
  ct.Canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(newPage);
// add text at an __absolute__ position      
  ct.SetSimpleColumn(
    marginOffset, marginOffset, 
    rectangle.Right - marginOffset, rectangle.Top - marginOffset
  );
  ct.Go();
}
```

I think you've already figured out that the `Document` / `PdfWriter` combination doesn't work in this situation :) That's the standard method for creating a **new** PDF document.