# Force new lines in text, inserted in existing pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, text, itext

So, I've seen an example for a newly created doc

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(400, 300);
Document doc = new Document(r);

try
{
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Blocks2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
    doc.Open();

    string text = @"The result can be seen below, which shows the text
      having been written to the document but it looks a
      mess. ";
    text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, String.Empty).Replace("  ", String.Empty);
    Font brown = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 9f, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(163, 21, 21));
    Font lightblue = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 9f, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(43, 145, 175));
    Font courier = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 9f);
    Font georgia = FontFactory.GetFont("georgia", 10f);
    georgia.Color = BaseColor.GRAY;
    Chunk beginning = new Chunk(text, georgia);
    Phrase p1 = new Phrase(beginning);
    Chunk c1 = new Chunk("You can of course force a newline using \"", georgia);
    Chunk c2 = new Chunk(@"\n", brown);
    Chunk c3 = new Chunk("\" or ", georgia);
    Chunk c4 = new Chunk("Environment", lightblue);
    Chunk c5 = new Chunk(".NewLine", courier);
    Chunk c6 = new Chunk(", or even ", georgia);
    Chunk c7 = new Chunk("Chunk", lightblue);
    Chunk c8 = new Chunk(".NEWLINE", courier);
    Chunk c9 = new Chunk(" as part of the string you give a chunk.", georgia);
    Phrase p2 = new Phrase();
    p2.Add(c1);
    p2.Add(c2);
    p2.Add(c3);
    p2.Add(c4);
    p2.Add(c5);
    p2.Add(c6);
    p2.Add(c7);
    p2.Add(c8);
    p2.Add(c9);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Add(p1);
    p.Add(p2);
    p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;

    doc.Add(p);
}
```

As you can see, the document is initiated with a rectangle `Document doc = new Document(r);`
So, the result of this code is gonna be like this

[image: new document]

My question is: how do I append text, which will consider page size in an existing document?

Is it possible to add a rectangle with a text in a doc? Or maybe append a newly created document to an existing one?

I realise, that I should probably read iText books, but I'm kind of running out of time and this is the last thing I have to figure out. Is there a clean easy solution, to my question? Thank you

**UPDATE:**

Sadly, for some reason the solution by Alexis Pigeon doesn't work for me.
I've written

```
Document doc = new Document();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("C:/Blocks2.pdf", FileMode.Open));
doc.Open();
```

and at the end

```
doc.Add(p); doc.Close()
```

And no changes are applied to the file, although code runs smoothly.
Something tells me, that this approach is wrong, since I haven't met any code examples, where people would have used `Document` with and existing pdf file, only creating a new one. Usually it's `PDFStamper` or `PDFWriter`.

So, let me rephrase my **question**: How do I append text to an existing document so that it will fill certain rectangle?

Comment: *Or maybe append a newly created document to an existing one?* - Simply create a new PDF and concatenate the existing PDF and your new one using `PdfCopy`.

Comment: The `Document` class (and more so the internal `PdfDocument`) is an abstraction over the PDF syntax that automatically takes care of things for you like "margin" and "paragraphs" and "current position" that don't actually exist in PDFs. When a PDF is actually generated these abstractions are converted to raw PDF commands and effectively lost. When "editing" an existing PDF, it is 100% up to you to calculate where all new text will be placed. However, once you manually calculate where things should go next you can use a [ColumnText](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9472064/231316)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after looking around I figured out, that what Im looking for is called "hyphenation". Didnt know this word.
To fit the text in a rectangle area you need to create a table with one cell and invisible borders. I've also encoutered issues with encoding. Here is the code.:

```
        PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader("Test1.pdf");
        File.Delete("C:/Blocks.pdf");
        PdfStamper stp = new PdfStamper(pdf, new FileStream("C:/Blocks.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

        var canvas = stp.GetOverContent(1);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 100 });
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
        phrase.Hyphenation = new HyphenationAuto("ru", "RU", 2, 2);
        var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf", "Cp1251", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        phrase.Add(new Chunk("О БОЖЕ ТЫ МОЙ НЕУЖЕЛИ РАБОТАЕТ ЕСЛИ РАБОТАЕТ Я БЫЛ БЫ ТАК СЧАСТЛИВ", new Font(bf, 12)));

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
        cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, 1, 200, 200, canvas);

        stp.Close();
```